Rewriting query
I have a scenario where I want to take only one row from a group based on the column values in TID column. For example my key columns in the table SRN,GIO and FID. Now there is another column TID, now within a group when two TIDS given in case statement are present in the group, then I need to take one with rank 1(calculated), otherwise we can take the other record. Also note that there are records which are not part of this conditions which should also come as output. Given sample records, and also expected output below
Input data



SRN
GIO
FID
TID




ASD123
1
100
218


ASD123
1
100
303


ASD123
1
100
454


ASD123
1
100
678


DEF234
0
6566
2222


DEF234
0
6566
307


DEF234
0
6566
2IUD


WER453
1
8123
308


WER453
1
8123
2wER


WER453
1
8123
56TY



I have written the query as below, but since there are multiple case conditions, its going for full table scan for each condition, which is causing performance as there are lot of records in the table. so is there a better way to rewrite this query.
    select case when TID in('218','303')
then RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SRN, GIO,FID ORDER BY CASE when TID ='218' then 1 else 2 END) end COL_3 ,
case when TID in('2222','307')
then RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SRN, GIO,FID ORDER BY CASE when TID ='2222' then 1 else 2 END) end COL_4 ,
case when TID in('2202','308')
then RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SRN, GIO,FID ORDER BY CASE when TID ='2202' then 1 else 2 END) end COL_5 ,
case when TID in('2220','305')
then RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SRN, GIO,FID ORDER BY CASE when TID ='2220' then 1 else 2 END) end COL_6 ,
case when TID in('2211','311')
then RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SRN, GIO,FID ORDER BY CASE when TID ='2211' then 1 else 2 END) end COL_7
from table where
((COL_3 = 1 or COL_4 = 1 OR COL_5=1 OR COL_6=1 OR COL_7=1)
OR
(COL_3 is null and COL_4 is null and COL_5 is null and COL_6 is null and COL_7 is null)
)

Expected output



SRN
GIO
FID
TID




ASD123
1
100
218


ASD123
1
100
454


ASD123
1
100
678


DEF234
0
6566
2222


DEF234
0
6566
2IUD


WER453
1
8123
308


WER453
1
8123
2wER


WER453
1
8123
56TY




Is it possible that multiple combinations such as ('218', '303') and ('2222', '307') exist per (SRN,GIO,FID)? Can there be more than two values to be ranked?

Yes there can be a chance that all this can exist under one group, so thats why we need separate ranking here

Then d r's answer is the best way, you just need to add p.pair to the PARTITION. Of course, it's also recommended to store the rules/logic in a table instead of a CTE.

To rewrite the query for better performance and avoid multiple full table scans, you can use a single ranking query with a CASE statement that dynamically handles all your conditions. This eliminates the need for multiple RANK operations for each condition, consolidating the logic into a single query.
You can try this:
WITH RankedData AS (
    SELECT
        SRN,
        GIO,
        FID,
        TID,
        RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY SRN, GIO, FID
            ORDER BY 
                CASE
                    WHEN TID IN ('218', '303') THEN 
                        CASE WHEN TID = '218' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
                    WHEN TID IN ('2222', '307') THEN 
                        CASE WHEN TID = '2222' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
                    WHEN TID IN ('2202', '308') THEN 
                        CASE WHEN TID = '2202' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
                    WHEN TID IN ('2220', '305') THEN 
                        CASE WHEN TID = '2220' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
                    WHEN TID IN ('2211', '311') THEN 
                        CASE WHEN TID = '2211' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
                    ELSE NULL
                END
        ) AS rank_in_group
    FROM your_table
),
FilteredData AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM RankedData
    WHERE rank_in_group = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM RankedData
    WHERE rank_in_group IS NULL
)
SELECT SRN, GIO, FID, TID
FROM FilteredData;


This is not going to work as-is: rank_in_group will never be NULL

It can be combined in one case statement and then ranking done on the required TIDs.
You can check the FIDDLE here
WITH RankedData AS (
  SELECT
    SRN,
    GIO,
    FID,
    TID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SRN, GIO, FID 
                        ORDER BY CASE WHEN TID IN ('218', '303', '2222', '307', '2202', '308', '2220', '305', '2211', '311') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS rn
  FROM
    input
)
SELECT
  SRN,
  GIO,
  FID,
  TID
FROM
  RankedData
WHERE
  (rn = 1 AND TID IN ('218', '303', '2222', '307', '2202', '308', '2220', '305', '2211', '311'))
  OR (rn > 1 
  AND TID NOT IN ('218', '303', '2222', '307', '2202', '308', '2220', '305', '2211', '311'));


You could create a CTE with predefined TID pairs and respective orders.
WITH
  pairs AS 
    ( Select 1 as pair, '218' as tid, 1 as ord Union All
      Select 1, '303',  2 Union All
      Select 2, '2222', 1 Union All
      Select 2, '307',  2 Union All
      Select 3, '2202', 1 Union All
      Select 3, '308',  2 Union All
      Select 4, '2220', 1 Union All
      Select 4, '305',  2 Union All
      Select 5, '2211', 1 Union All
      Select 5, '311',  2 
    )

... now Left Join pairs cte to your table data, calculate ranks and filter to rank 1 or no matching pair ...
--      M a i n    S Q L : 
SELECT    a.srn, a.gio, a.fid, a.tid
FROM     ( Select    t.*,
                     Coalesce(p.pair, 0) as pair, 
                     Rank() Over(Partition By t.srn, t.gio, t.fid Order By p.ord) as rnk
           From      tbl t
           Left Join pairs p ON( p.tid = t.tid)
         ) a
WHERE     a.rnk = 1 OR a.pair = 0
ORDER BY  a.srn, a.gio, a.fid;

... this code uses Left Join instead of your Case expressions simplifying Where clause conditions too ...
R e s u l t :



srn
gio
fid
tid




ASD123
1
100
218


ASD123
1
100
454


ASD123
1
100
678


DEF234
0
6566
2222


DEF234
0
6566
2IUD


WER453
1
8123
308


WER453
1
8123
2wER


WER453
1
8123
56TY



fiddle
